# Pass button value to Url.Action in a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, button

How can I go about passing this value on a button(the button starts the js onclick):

```
<button class="launch" value= @item.Id  role="button" name="dId">do it</button>
```

to a `$(this).load("@Url.Action("myPartial", new { id = 1 })");`

I am looking to replace the `1` with the `@item.Id` value from the button.  Thanks.

Here is the script:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("modal").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 600,
            width: 700,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("myPartial", new { id = 1 })");
            },
                buttons:{
                    "Close": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
        });
        $(".launch").click(function () {
            $("#modal").dialog("open");
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: use `this.value` to get the value

Answer (score 2):

Add an id to your button:

**Html:**

```
<button class="launch" value= "@item.Id" id="button" role="button" name="dId">do it</button>
```

**JS:**

```
var button=document.getElementById("button");
$(this).load("@Url.Action("myPartial", new { id ="button.value" })");
```

Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: When I add the button to the URL Action it gives me the name button does not exist in the current context, but I put it in the line above.

Comment: I did add the id... still says the error.  I added the script is it because where I placed it?

Comment: Try giving quotes to the value and if it still persists,remove the role option in the button.

Comment: I did both of those and still there same error under button in id = button.value

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51993/discussion-between-nevin-madhukar-k-and-shawn)

Comment: The name 'button' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Do a fiddle,then i will help you out.
Its kinda hard for me to do it without your entire code.

http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @EhsanSajjad This is C#?

Comment: i mean razor code Url.Action helper you used, i mean to say we can razor or c# variable to js but not js variable to razor, please correct me if i am wrong